# Unable to send string from client(Android App) to server(C++)

Tags: java, android, c++, server, client

Iam new to this android development. I am trying to send a string from android app(Java) to server(C++). If I test these files alone instead of adding java file to the android I am able to send that string(verified). But once if I place the java file in android studio I am unable to send that string. Can someone help me in this.
Thanks in advance.

Client Code

```
---
out = new PrintStream(this.socket.getOutputStream());
---
public int sendDataToServer(String data) {
        Log.i(TAG, data);

        try {
                out.print(data+"\n");
                out.flush();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return flag;
    }
```

Server Code

```
valread = read(new_socket, buffer, 1024);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
```

Comment: How does your Android client send data to the server without that Java code?

Comment: Further it is unclear to me if the client cannot send a string or that the server does not receive the string sent by the client.

Comment: `valread = read(new_socket, buffer, 1024);` Waht does this statement if the client only sent for instance 100 bytes, does it hang?

Comment: The Client Code is in Java already. Iam able to get the data till before this ```out.print(data+"\n");``` Verified using logs. The thing is I just want to send a string from that java client(which is in android) to c++ server. I don't want to worry about any length. ```valread = read(new_socket, buffer, 1024);``` This ```read()``` is unable to get the data which is sent by client. I don't understand whether client is not sending or read is not receiving.

Comment: You did not answer my question to the point. Repeat: `valread = read(new_socket, buffer, 1024)`  Whatt does this statement if the client only sent for instance 100 bytes, does it hang? –

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, No it does not hang